# making a text edit field

Tags: javascript, html, css, text-editor, onenote

I am a beginner in HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript.  I reached my limit for the use of the trial version of Microsoft's OneNote.  I like the program so much, I want to make an equivalent of it as an html version so I won't have to empty my pockets for the paid version.

The part I need help with is the part where you type in your notes.  I don't know how to make a text edit field in html.  Is it possible to do something like that?  I would be satisfied if it could only do the same functions as note pad.  Just so long as I am able to do the simple type and edit functions.  Can someone show me how to code this or lead me to a site that teaches something like this?

Thanks!  Tony.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of solutions out there.  Nicedit, CKEditor, etc.  These all have a Rich text interface, and are javascript managed.

The simplest solution would be to just use a `<textarea>` which would allow for plain text input only.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the `<textarea>` tag in HTML. See this [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/textarea.html) too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use HTML5 Data caching to save your notes locally through your browser after implementing your textarea tags.

Here's a neat little plugin that should be relatively minor to install/use.

https://github.com/ekdevdes/storage.js

Comment: Wow! Thanks Christopher!  I was just wondering how I would be able to do that!  You're the Bomb!

Comment: No problem dude :} Here's the test page if you couldn't find it as it was hard to find. http://ek.alphaschildren.org/projects/storagejs/ Be sure to mark the question as answered by clicking on the arrow next to the vote counter. Happy coding!